# How to hook into views field criteria dropdown filter

Tags: 7, views

I have created a custom view which allows me to filter my nodes by my taxonomy 'city'. The nodes are linked to the taxonomy by a term reference. I need to be able to programatically remove values from the dropdown list of cities which are shown as a filter form on the view.

I have looked at hook_field_views_data_alter() - I am sure the answer lies here but not sure where to go with it.

So basically, I want to pragmatically edit these values which are shown in my view.

[image: I want to programatically edit these values]

Comment: Don't just look at hook. Try to implement it and see what happens :)

Comment: The only way I can see of doing anything is by creating a custom filter handler. However it looks like I have to write the whole thing from the bottom up? (http://www.chadcf.com/blog/creating-custom-filters-drupal-and-views)

Seems overkill just to take some values out of a form element?

Comment: Quick and dirty method is to use hook_form_alter, of course. Maybe there is better, more "proper views" way, too - I will not answer, because I don't know it, and I hope someone do.